# Some Questions on the Collatz conjecture (reexpressed as "equivalence relation")

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, open-problems, collatz-conjecture

The set of all positive whole numbers is denoted by $\mathbb{N}_+$.

Let $f\colon\ \mathbb{N}_+\to\mathbb{N}_+:n\mapsto
\begin{cases}\frac{n}{2}&\text{$n$ even}\\3n+1&\text{$n$ odd}\end{cases}$.

**Conjecture** (Collatz). $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_+.\ \exists N\in\mathbb{N}.\ f^N(n)=1$.

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_+$. We define: $m\sim n:\iff\exists N_1, N_2\in\mathbb{N}.\ f^{N_1}(m)=f^{N_2}(n)$.

It is easy to see that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}_+$. If we suppose the truth of the Collatz conjecture, then there is only one equivalence class.

> 1. How to prove that there is only a finite number of equivalence classes of $\sim$? Has somebody ever proven this? Or is the question whether there is only a finite number of equivalence classes *open*?
> 2. Is there an algorithm solving the following *decision problem*?
>
> INSTANCE: A pair $(m, n)\in\mathbb{N}_+\times\mathbb{N}_+$
>
> QUESTION: Does $m\sim n$ hold?

Comment: If the algorithm in your second question existed, it is hard to imagine why one would be unable to settle the Collatz conjecture by applying it to the special case $(m, 1)$.

Comment: Why? Suppose we had such an algorithm. Then we could ask whether $4\sim 1$, and we would get the answer "yes". Then we could ask whether $2745092318751409285702345\sim 1$, and we would also get an answer. Why does having such an algorithm imply that $\forall m.\ m\sim 1$?

Comment: If the algorithm terminates for every pair $(m,1)$ (and there is a proof that it does so), then by looking at the set of all $m$ for which the algorithm outputs "no" one obtains a precise characterization of the set of all counterexamples to the Collatz conjecture.  It's hard to imagine how such a characterization would not lead to either a proof or a counterexample for the conjecture itself.

Comment: Why does one definitely obtain a precise characterization if we had such an algorithm? The question "For which inputs does this algorithm halt" can be open, though.

Comment: Well, here's an algorithm: Replace $(m, n)$ with $(f(m), f(n))$ and repeat, halting and outputting "yes" if both $f(m)$ and $f(n)$ are in the set $\{1,2,4\}$.  This algorithm halts for all inputs if and only if the Collatz conjecture is true.

Comment: @PaulSiegel I can imagine a scenario in which there is a computable number $f(n)$ such that if, after iterating Collatz operation on $n$ $f(n)$ times we don't get $1$, we will never reach $1$. Then relation $\sim$ is clearly computable, but by no means it implies Collatz conjecture is true.

Comment: We can consider a variation of this problem, in which $f(n)=n+1$ or $f(n)=n-1$. $\sim$ is in both cases trivially computable, since $n\sim m$ for all $n,m$, but we can't infer from these whether "Collatz conjecture" holds for $f$, since in the first case it doesn't, while in the latter - it does.

Comment: @Wojowu In the case of the function $f(n) = n + 1$ the naive algorithm "replace $(m,n)$ with $(f(m),f(n))$" doesn't work, but there is a more sophisticated algorithm which does work: define $g(n)$ to be $n - 1$ if $n > 1$ and $1$ otherwise.  Replace $(m,n)$ with $(g(m), g(n))$ and repeat until $g(m) = g(n) = 1$.  There is a simple proof that this algorithm halts, and notice that when you apply this argument to $(m, 1)$ you get a simple proof of the Collatz conjecture for $f$.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how we could have an algorithm which decides ~ and a proof that it halts but not a proof or a counter-example for Collatz.  But it could be a failure of my own imagination.

Comment: (Said differently: it looks to me like we are trying to compute the number of Collatz equivalence classes when we don't even know if there is more than 1.)

Comment: There is an algorithm for "Does m∼n hold?".  Namely: Answer YES.  That algorithm works!  But (unfortunately) this comment box is too small to contain the proof.

Comment: @Paul Siegel If a Collatz sequence cannot diverge to infinity, then the equivalence relation is decidable: Just keep computing the next element (and store all previous ones), until the cycle has been completed. Now one just has to check whether both starting points have reached the same or different cycles. In fact, it would suffice it there were at most one diverging sequence. This algorithm doesn't really tell us anything about how many different cycles there might be.

Comment: @Arno: doesn't that idea only say,that *... if we try all numbers to check their equivalence-class, then ...* But how can *that* be seen as an improvement over the original Collatz-transformation (with the (infinite) task of checking each number separately)?

Comment: @Gottfried Just using the formulation of the Collatz transformation, there is no immediate way to prove that two numbers are not in the same equivalence class; or in the special case, that a particular number does not eventually reach 0. If we knew that a cycle has to be reached, then we could wait until that happens, and then just look at the cycle (which is a suitable finite object).

Comment: Unfortunately, it may not be decidable even if there is only one diverging sequence: it depends on how quickly different trajectories converge.  I can imagine a situation where m and n are equal only after g(m,n) steps where g is not a recursive function.  Gerhard "Recursion Is A Tricky Concept" Paseman, 2016.03.12.

Answer (score 11):

This problem is still open.  See for example Sections 2.6 and 2.7 of [Lagarias's survey](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Lagarias3-23.pdf).